# How can i print all the numbers of the array until [i][j] position?

Tags: c++

```
 void array::printArray(int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << Arr[i][j] << " ";
        } cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl; 
}
```

Why does this code not print all the elements until the position given?
sample array:

81 843 114 320

128 205 587 165

input:

n= 2

j= 3

output:

81 843 114

128 205 587

What I was expecting:

81 843 114 320

128 205 587

Comment: what is `Arr` ?

Comment: An array of type Arr

Comment: It does, provided `Arr` is a valid reference to an array structure, double check the code calling the array, and the arguments you're passing to it (a debugger helps). Also show your output

Comment: where is it defined? why aren't you passing array to function also?

Comment: Assuming it is already defined. I made some changes and included and example input/ouput case

Comment: `j` should be `4`. There is no problem with your `printArray()`. Are you sure that you are passing correct row number and column number to `printArray()`? You should post the code which is calling this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Be careful because array is an STL container, so array::printArray will generate a compiling error.

2) You have to pass your container "Arr" to the function, unless it's a class member/global variable
3) Looking at your example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < rows ; ++i )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < cols ; ++j ) 
    {
        cout << Arr[i][j] << " ";

        if ( i == n - 1 && 
             j == m - 1 )
        {
            return ;
        }
    } 
    cout << endl;
}
```

where rows is the total number of rows, cols is the total number of columns in your array

Comment: I added another edit in regards to the output I was expecting. Maybe its a bit more clear now.

Comment: so you want to print all the elements minus the last one? regardless of the array's size?

Comment: I want to print all the elements up until the given position (which is given by the user)

Comment: I modified my answer above. Let me know if it works

Comment: It works! I couldn't understand the logic of this for a long time!!

Comment: What you can do is iterate over the entire array as if you're gonna print the whole thing, but when you get to the element you wanna stop at, you "return", the equivalent of breaking the two for loops

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with `printArray()` function.
The sample array

```
81 843 114 320

128 205 587 165
```

size is `2x4` i.e. `2` row and `4` column.

You are passing `2` and `3` to `printArray()`:

```
input:

n= 2

j= 3
```

i.e. `2` row and `3` column.

The in-memory view of array `Arr` would be something like this:

```
          col-0  col-1 col-2 col-3
         --------------------------
  row-0  |  81  | 843 | 114 | 320 |
         --------------------------
  row-1  | 128  | 205 | 587 | 165 |
         --------------------------
```

So, for the given input, the expected output:

```
81 843 114

128 205 587
```

as for every row, the number of columns printed `3`.

Pass the correct value of number of columns of `Arr` array.

---

Edit

OP updated question with this, while I was writing answer:

```
What I was expecting:

81 843 114 320

128 205 587
```

For this kind of output, you have to make changes in `printArray()`. When printing last row, print one element less. But why you want this kind of output? When printing an array, you should print it's all element.

Comment: Amazing explanation! Helps a lot to visualize the logic of this!

Comment: Oh and to answer your question, yes, that is indeed true. I've already made a function to print all the elements of any given array but i thought about this exercise and thought it was simple and tried to do it. Keep in mind, I am still a beginner and have very little programming knowledge and i'm still developing the logic and aptitude for problem solving.